# Using Count based on query result in SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hi I have a Table in which I want to count and categorized result by subtracted the values in each colum.

```
StartDate          EndDate
09:45              10:30
10:00              12:00
10:30              11:00
11:00              17:00
11:15              12:00
```

In the above table I want to know how many finished in less than 2hours and how many finihsed above 2hour.
Results would look like this:

```
Below 2hours       2hours and Above
3                    2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the above select statement but you need just to add count function as below

```
select
    count(Below_2hours) AS Below_2hours,
    count(2hours_and_Above) AS 2hours_and_Above from
    (
    select
        case
            when DATEDIFF(HH,start_time,end_time) <2 then 'Below_2hours'
            when DATEDIFF(HH,start_time,end_time) >2 then '2hours_and_Above'
        end  from Table_Name ) AS A
```

Comment: Please complete the code with the appropriate parenthesis as its creating error when i pasted the code.

Comment: Im getting an invalid Below_2Hours column, and 2hours_and_Above also the column is invalid...

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when DATEDIFF(HH,start_time,end_time) <1 then 'below one hour'
   when DATEDIFF(HH,start_time,end_time) <2 then 'below 2 hour'
    when DATEDIFF(HH,start_time,end_time) <3 then 'below 3 hour'
     when DATEDIFF(HH,start_time,end_time) <4 then 'below 4 hour'
      when DATEDIFF(HH,start_time,end_time) <5 then 'below 5 hour'
      else 'above 5'
      end  from WU_DATAMART_ETL_LOG
```

pls try this code

Comment: What will i put in the from clause?  The 2 colums are joined from two different tables. Start date from table 1 and End Date from Table 2..